# Not in returing zero rows Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What's wrong with the following query.

I am passing 4 values as input to this query and I am expecting three rows as output.
 Because Out of the 4 values one of them exist in the listing_cart table. 
But it is returning `0` rows.

```
 DECLARE 
    @AgentID varchar(20),
    @StringValues varchar(max),
    @ContactKey int,
    @Note varchar(255)


    SET @AgentID = 'c110010'
    SET @StringValues  = '08-328222,08-337333,09-348444,09-352555'
    SET @ContactKey = 0
    SET @Note = ''

     SELECT   @AgentID as agentid,mlsnum,'New' as status,ADDRESS,@Note as notes,PROPERTY_TYPE as propertytype FROM mls_unified_svo_tbl (nolock)
                    WHERE mlsnum IN (Select txt From [dbo].[fn_ListToTable](@StringValues, ','))
                    AND mlsnum  NOT IN (select mlsnum from listing_cart (nolock) where agentid = @AgentID and contact_key = @ContactKey)
```

Comment: Your query is depends on some factors we haven't see. 1. What is the result of `Select txt From [dbo].[fn_ListToTable](@StringValues, ',')` for given value for `@StringValues` 2. What is the result of second subquery .... 3. the data contained in `mls_unified_svo_tbl`.

Comment: I pass in 'mlsnums' separated by comma as text  to the fn_listToTable and it returns a table of mlsnums.   The purpose of this query is get those records which exist in 'mls_unified_svo_tbl' but not in 'listing_cart'

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
 SELECT @AgentID as agentid, mlsnum, 'New' as status, ADDRESS, @Note as notes,
        PROPERTY_TYPE as propertytype
 FROM mls_unified_svo_tbl
 WHERE mlsnum IN (Select txt From [dbo].[fn_ListToTable](@StringValues, ',')) AND
       mlsnum NOT IN (select mlsnum
                      from listing_cart 
                      where agentid = @AgentID and contact_key = @ContactKey
                     );
```

There are numerous things that could be going wrong, apart from the obvious condition that there are no matches.  You should checK:

- `fn_ListToTable(@StringValues, ',')` actually returns the values you are expecting.  In particular, that there are no extra characters at the beginning or ending of the strings.
- That `listing_cart` has a column called `mlsnum` and this is never `NULL`.
- I would be very careful about columns in the subqueries, and use this instead:

  ```
     mlsnum NOT IN (select lc.mlsnum
                    from listing_cart lc
                    where lc.agentid = @AgentID and lc.contact_key = @ContactKey
                   )
  ```

One possibility is that `listing_cart` called the `mlsnum` something else.  The query works, because the value is correlated to the outer table, but then `not in` always returns false.